Migration from one Mac to another causes Chrome failure in distinguishing the two computers?
I bought a new iMac and migrated files using Migration Assistant.app from my MacBook Air to the new iMac. Chrome shows only one device at https://myaccount.google.com/device-activity on both devices when I logged in with google account on both devices.
However I expect two sessions/devices present in the list shown in Chrome, since in fact I am having two computers. I have tried logout and login, and deleting history on one device.
The failure in identifying multiple devices may cause that the Chromes on the two devices do not share history with each other, which makes switch between the two devices problematic.
Any suggestion?

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
